# validation two fileds in laravel validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have 2 fields to check validation...

```
parent
tag
```

I want something like this:

```
if(parent == 0)
     return 'tag is required';
else 
    return 'tag can be nullable';
```

I try something like this but it is wrong:

```
'parent' => 'nullable|numeric',
'tags' => 'required_with:parent=0|array|max:8',
```

Comment: Would you please share the method in which you have your validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`required_if`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-if) rule.

> The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.

```
'parent' => 'nullable|numeric',
'tags' => 'required_if:parent,0|array|max:8',
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-if